# Вывод изображений в yii2

Tags: yii2

Всем доброго времени суток! Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

Подключил виджет costa-rico/yii2-images. Все работает: фото грузит, удаляет, но во вьюхе не выводит изображения. Yii ошибок не показывает. В браузер html код картинок вставляется, но браузер выдает ошибку 404.

[image: скрин отображения в браузере]

Код вьюхи:

```
<?php 

    use yii\helpers\Html;
    use yii\widgets\DetailView;

    $images = $model->getImages();
    $data = '';
    foreach ($images as $image) {
        $data .= Html::img($image->getUrl(), ['alt' => 'objphoto']);
    }
?>

<?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
        ........
        [
            'attribute' => 'images',
            'format' => 'html',
            'value' => $data,              
        ],
        .......
    ],
]) ?>
```

Comment: Покажите конфигурацию модуля

Comment: Денис, судя по-всему дело в ссылках. Я методом научного тыка вышел на следующий код, который сработал $data .= Html::img('/uploads/realty/'.$image->filePath, ['alt' => 'objphoto','height' => 200]); Почему-то код из документации оказался нерабочим.

Comment: Ну не совсем тыка)) Я в принципе понял, чтоCostaRico меняет ссылки, видимо шифрует реальные пути к файлам. У него в документации за это отвечает метод getUrl();.При этом в БД сохраняется filePath с нормальной ссылкой на файл. Вот он и работает.

Comment: Добрый вечер. А где хранится информация об изображениях?

Comment: Добрый день! инфа хранится в БД в таблице. После установки виджета надо сделать миграцию таблицы через composer, точнее две миграции. Первая добавляет собственно таблицу image, а вторя добавляет в таблицу столбец name. Правда у меня он почему-то всегда пустой.